# Cout vs. \n (newline character): Which is faster when running a program?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm working on a program that prints different statements. In the following code, which case would be faster?

Case 1:

```
    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Email is not found in the database" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------\n" << endl;
```

Case 2:

```
    cout << "----------------------------------\nEmail is not found in the database\n----------------------------------\n" << endl;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried both (at varying optimization levels) and checked to see how much time they take?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n

Comment: Since `endl` does more than ending a line, I'm confident it's the second one. Will it be measurable? Writing this question might have taken more time than the optimized code will ever save.

Comment: @Quimby -- if standard in has been redirected to a file, `'\n'` will be much faster than `std::endl`. `std::endl` should only be used when it's needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker `stdout`, even.

Comment: @PaulSanders — whoops, that’s what I meant. :-(

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to the best of us @Pete.  Anyway, you made a good point there, so many people don't seem to understand the difference.